# Game runs fine on newer devices but not on older

Tags: android, libgdx

My games runs fine on newer devices (eg..droid turbo, galaxy note 3) but on my motorola xoom there are problems, such as :

1) My shaderProgram causes the stage that is drawn inside of it to not be rendered

2) Touch inputs don't work every time using InputProcessor (only senses 90% of the time)

These are the problems I currently notice. Could this be because it is an older OS version (4.1.2)? Not that old. Are known bugs with libgdx's ShaderProgram? Even then, the touch input not sensing every click is very strange. Thanks for your time and help! My rendering code for the shaderProgram is all correct, so no need to show that. And for touchInput, I am just using touchDown method from InputProcessor.

EDIT :
Error produced by shaderProgram
"(22) : error C1101: ambiguous overloaded function reference "smoothstep(mediump float, float, lowp float)"

Vertex Shader

```
#version 100

attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;

uniform mat4 u_worldView;
uniform vec2 u_lightPos;
uniform vec3 u_lightColor;
uniform vec4 u_spaceColor;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
varying vec2 v_lightPos;
varying vec3 v_lightColor;
varying vec2 v_position;
varying vec4 v_spaceColor;

void main() {
    v_color = a_color;
    v_lightColor = u_lightColor;
    v_lightPos = u_lightPos;
    v_position.xy = a_position.xy;
    v_texCoords = a_texCoord0;
    gl_Position =  u_worldView * a_position;
    v_spaceColor = u_spaceColor;
}
```

Fragment Shader

```
#version 100

#ifdef GL_ES
precision lowp float;
#endif

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
varying vec2 v_lightPos;
varying vec3 v_lightColor;
varying vec2 v_position;
varying vec4 v_spaceColor;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main() {

    for(int row = 0; row < 2; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < 2; col++) {
            float dist = distance(v_position, vec2(-1 + col, 1 - row));
            float delta = 0.1;
            float alpha = smoothstep(100.0-delta, 100.0, dist);

            if(dist > 23.0){
                gl_FragColor = mix(v_spaceColor, v_color, alpha);
            }
            else{
                gl_FragColor = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your shader does not adhere strictly to the OpenGL ES Shading Language Specification, it may fail to work on a seemingly random assortment of devices, regardless of OS version. Various GPUs permit some syntax that isn't strictly compliant with the language spec, which can make it tricky to debug because it will work on some devices OK. Log `shaderProgram.getLog()` after instantiating it to find out what line(s) of code in the shader is causing the issue.

Comment: I can't explain the touch issue (I've never had any issue in my released apps so it's doubtful there is a problem with LibGDX). You may be using it in an unusual way, so it would help to see your code.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I will log that and see what happens. I fixed the touch issue by not using a input multiplexer. So I now just set each stage as the processor when necessary. Not sure why this fixed that problem.

Comment: Looks like you are mixing different float precisions together as inputs to the smoothstep function. Post your code and I can tell you what to try.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Added code. I appreciate your help more than you can imagine!

Comment: I don't think lowp should really be used for anything besides color vectors, so I'd recommend using mediump. I think your constants (100.0) are ambiguous in precision because you don't declare them anywhere. I usually declare constants outside the method and use the variable in your expression and method call. Then the precision will be unambiguous.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Switching to mediump seems to have fixed the problem. Thank you very much!